# How to translate using translations editor in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, translation

In my project, I have lots of string resources. Now that I am planning for release of my first ever app, I wanted to translate those to some widely used languages. However, I was unable to find the translate button there. This may seem dumb, but I am searching for it from an hour or so. I even have latest version of android studio installed. I gone through this [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor) and it was no help. Can someone please tell me how to translate strings using translations editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in my case it does show a notification when I open strings.xml (res -> values -> strings.xml) saying: "Edit translations for all locales in the translations editor" and then, in the right, it has two options: "Open editor" which opens the translation editor in a new tab and "Hide notification" which hides that notification.

Now, I think if you can't see that you might have accidentally hidden that notification. If so, you can also open the translation editor by opening Project tab (left), then find your strings.xml file (res -> values -> strings.xml) and right-click on it. In my version (Chipmunk | 2021.2.1) the bottom option says Open Translations Editor. Click it and you're right in the translations editor! As for the question, it does seem a little dumb, but I understand you're a beginner (and I was one too some time ago), so there's no problem!

Hope it helps and your app succeeds!
Good luck! :)

The notification about the translation editor:

[image: The notification about the translation editor]